# How to create notification when Elasticsearch insert matches postgres record

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, architecture, notifications

I've met a problem while designing proper solution for Notification system. I have a AWS Lambda function which inserts data to Elasticsearch when file occurs in AWS S3. Second part of the system is application for users where one of the functionality is to create query based on which records from ElasticSearch are returned and shown as a result and the query can be saved on User profile in app (this is stored in Postgres). Now the new part of the system comes which are Notifications. Users should get email when newly inserted record in Elasticsearch matches user's stored query in Postgres database. I was thinking about creating Elasticsearch "percolate" for each user query but I am not sure if that will affect ES performance and if that's best solution.
What do you think?